# Nginx: Invalidate cache for request A when request B is received

Tags: nginx, cache

I have URI A that retrieves a list from a server, it's a long process that I would like to cache.

I have another URI B, which updates the collection retrieved by URI A, and so the cache is invalid.

Is there anyway, to invalidate Niginx cache for A when a request is made for B.

I can't set a time limit, the frequency of updates (request B) can range from few seconds to few days

Thank you

Comment: You would probably need to provide examples of what the URL's contain such as content type, what cache control headers you or the app are setting, if the demarcation is a query string and relevant snippets of your nginx configuration.

Comment: [Nginx Plus](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/caching/) has better cache invalidation support than open source Nginx. I couldn't get [Nginx Cache Purge](http://labs.frickle.com/nginx_ngx_cache_purge/) to work with Wordpress, but it's worth looking at.